# How to determine if an inner class implements an interface?

Tags: java, class, interface, inner-classes

I have this code:

```
public class test{

    private testInterface i1;

    public test(testInterface i1) {
        this.i1 = i1;
   
    }
     test() {
    }
   

    interface testInterface {
    
        }

 class inner1 implements testInterface {

    }
 class inner2 implements testInterface {

    }
 class inner3 implements testInterface {

    }

     public void determineClass_Interfac(){
      }
}

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test test1 =new test(new test().new inner1());
    }
}
```

I don't know if that could work but what I'm trying to achieve is to determine, by calling the method determineClass_Interfac(), which inner class object was created. So, it should be dependent on the object that was created in the class constructor (here innerClass1).
My approach could be totally wrong, I'm just experimenting here.

Comment: What is the goal here? Let's say you found out, what's the use?

Comment: use instanceof operator.

Comment: If you only need to know if a certain inner (or other) class implements an interface you can use `instanceof`.  For example: `inner1 test1 = new test().new inner1();  System.out.println(test1 instanceof testInterface);`

Comment: Please follow [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `instanceof` operator to know if a particular instance is implementing a particular interface or class.

So the code

```
public interface MyInterface { 
   ...
}

public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {
   ...
}
```

You can check that

```
MyInterface myInterface = new MyInterfaceImpl();
if (myInterface instanceof MyInterface) {
     // It goes here because myInterface object is of type MyInterfaceImpl implementing the MyInterface
}

MyInterfaceImpl myInterfaceImpl = new MyInterfaceImpl();
if (myInterfaceImplinstanceof MyInterface) {
     // Also now you go in the if because the runtime type of myInterfaceImpl
     // is implementing your interface
}
```

This approach works for any kind of class and interface. Is not important if the class is an inner class or not.

---

I give you also some tip:

- Use meaningful names for methods and classes
- Use UpperCase for name of classes and interfaces
- Probably you should use static for nested classes if you need to instantiate them from outside the context of outer class.
- The method `determineClass_Interfac` should take as argument the object that you would like to test.

Comment: You are right... inner class is the wrong word. Nested class is better. If you need to instantiate that class outside any existing instance of the container class you need to create it as static.